# Why these two code snippets equivalent to each other (Pointers)

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I'm writing a function to find the length of a linked list. My question is specific to the declaration of a pointer.

```
int lengthOfLinkedList(Node *head) 
{ 
Node* current = head; 
}

vs. 

int lengthOfLinkedList(Node *head) 
{
Node* current = NULL; 
current = head; 
}
```

So here's my understanding:
In the first example a pointer that points to a Node object is declared and it dereferences the address of the head pointer.

---

| Memory address |  <--- current

---

This is not what I want to do. Instead I want to deference the pointer so I can access a node it is pointing to (which is what I did in the second code snippet):

---

|data| *next| <--- current

---

So now I am thinking that pointers act differently when you initialize them - you can directly declare a pointer to a memory address when you initialize it by using the('*') operator but you could no longer do this after initialization. That's pretty odd..

Am I right or is there something else going on?

Comment: The first initializes `current` with the value in `head`. The second initializes `current` with the value `NULL` and then assigns the value in `head` to `current`.

Comment: `current` is of type "pointer to Node". Both code snippets do exactly the same thing. The first initialized "current" in the declaration. The second initializes "current" to NULL first, then resets it to "head" in an assignment statement.

Comment: Remember that pointers are still represented by a value (memory address), the value of `current` will equal the value of `head` in either case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two snippets are perfectly equivalent; in both cases `*` is *not* the dereferentiation operator (as it would be if it occurred in an expression), but it's just a token used to declare a pointer. In other words, here `*` logically<sup>1</sup> goes with `Node` (as to specify the type `Node*`, i.e. "pointer to `Node`"<sup>2</sup>), not with `current`.

(This confusing reuse of the same character for two completely different things (pointer specifier in declarations, unary operator in expressions<sup>3</sup>) comes from the fact that C has the idea that "declarations should mimick usage", so, since to access the value of a pointer you use `*`, it is used even to declare them.)

In the first case, `current` starts from the beginning with the same value of `head`, in the second case first it's initialized to `NULL`, then is changed to have the same value of `head`; in both cases, at the end of the function the result is exactly the same.

---

1. Sadly, syntactically it goes with `current`, since in declarations the "pointer type specifier" is bound to the specific variable; i.e., if you write `int * ptr1, ptr2;`, `ptr1` will be of type `int *`, while `ptr2` will be a plain `int`.
2. Pointers declarations are best understood when read from right to left (`const char *`: pointer to a character constant; `char * const`: constant pointer to character; and so on); more general declarations (e.g. function pointers) are [way messier](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html).
3. Also, binary multiplication operator, but usually there's no confusion (it works on different types and is put between two operands).

Comment: Interesting. So * is used to declare a pointer and then [i]after[/i] it has been initialized you can use * to dereference it. No wonder why pointers are so confusing to many people. One operator performs two distinct functions

Comment: @user2202911: I agree, it's quite confusing at the beginning, almost every people I know that learned C or C++ has been bit by this ambiguity (by the way, notice that in the declaration it's not an operator, it's just a token used to specify that we want to declare a pointer)

Comment: @user2202911 And lots of C books put the whitespace between the type and the asterisk just to make it thoroughly confusing to beginners.

Comment: @Theodoros: they do because of the reason explained in note 1. As for me, I put whitespace both before and after, as to irritate the maximum number of people.

Comment: The answer to note 1: don't declare more than one variable per statement.  This feature is a hold-over from C, from a time when _all_ of the variables had to be declared at the top of the function, and has no place in well written C++.  (If you had a nested loop in C, it sort of made sense to declare the indices `int i, j;`.  In C++, and in modern C, you'd put the declarations directly in the `for`.)

Comment: Re note 2: If you want to read from right to left, you should always put the `const` to the right of what it modifies, i.e. `int const ci;` is a const int, `int *const cpi;` a const pointer to int, and `int const* pci;` a pointer to const int.

Comment: @JamesKanze: *I* usually don't declare more variables on a row, but it's important to know the fact outlined in note 1 because OP may see code written by others and get confused; as for 2, yes, it reads better, but even with `const` on the left works fine: "character constant" ("a constant whose type is char") is substantially the same as "constant character" ("a character that is constant").

Comment: @MatteoItalia Re 2: the main argument for putting the `const` to the right is with typedefs: `typedef int* PI; const PI pi;` gives `pi` the type `int* const`, not `const int*`.  (And of course, there's consistency; the `const` must follow in most cases.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no dereferencing in either example. Both merely assign the passed pointer to a new variable, which is then discarded when the function exits.

Consider this sequence

```
int x = 0;
x = 2;
```

vs.

```
int x = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

An *initialization* is not the same thing as an *assignment*; you are not dereferencing `current` in the intitialization.  The `*` is only there to indicate that `current` has a pointer type, and nothing more.

C and C++ declaration syntax is based on the types of *expressions*, not objects.  For example, if you have a pointer to an integer, and you want to get to that integer value, you must dereference the pointer with the unary `*` operator:

```
x = *p;
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is `int`, so it follows that the declaration for `p` is

```
int *p;
```

In a declaration, the `*` token is there simply to supply additional type information; namely, that `p` is a pointer to an `int`.  It's important to note that for a pointer declaration `T *p`, the `*` is bound to the declarator, not the type specifier.  IOW, `T *p;` is parsed as `T (*p);`.  Thus, if you want to declare multiple pointers in a single declaration, you'd have to write

```
T *p, *q, *r;
```

In this instance, each of `p`, `q`, and `r` are pointers to type `T`.

A lot of C++ programmers use the `T* p;` style, because they feel it's more important to emphasize the type of the object `p`, and there are times where it makes the intent of the code  clearer.  However, it will always be parsed as `T (*p);`.

Answer (score -1):

To help separate pointer declarations from de-referencing, consider using the arrow operator `->` when de-referencing. For example, `*current.data` is equivalent to `current->data`; `current->next` will give you the node pointed by current's next pointer.

Comment: this does not answer the question and is also wrong. `*current.data` is **not** equivalent to `current->data` while `(*current).data` is.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I agree that I chose poorly to use an answer with which to comment. The author  said "I want to deference the pointer so I can access a node it is pointing to" and I addressed an alternative option for doing so - having noticed his post was already answered.